# Which technique could I use to increase my resistance to slashing and piercing damage?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

In Dungeon of Dredmor, every time I reach dugoen level 4/5 things are getting hard. In particular I have some problems with monsters that cause slashing and/or piercing damage like Pumpkinn and Witchy.

I tried increasing my dodging chance but they hit me anyway 4 times out of 5. Also damage absorption seems to not be enough, and they attack me with 4-8 damage and even more if they crit.

Using a warrior slashing monsters are less dangerous but piercing monsters still hit hard; using a rogue or a mage I have problem with both.

Do you have any suggestions how to fight and survive these type of mobs?

Comment: What type of character do you have? If you've got heavy armour then don't bother with dodge as armour reduces it by so much that you won't get it to worthwhile levels (concentrate of block instead). But if you're a mage or using light armour, it sounds like your dodge stat is way too low.

Comment: It's general, I found it difficult with each archetype I tried. The last one was a rougue but even with high dodging stats they were able to hit me almost ever.

Comment: Maybe they have enermy dodge reduction? Still my last run I was heavily armoured - several enemies on that floor couldn't hurt me... Pumpkinns were an exception so they do quite a bit of damage.

Comment: My way of dealing with it involved going all out on the archaelogist skill tree and reactivating all the anvils of Krong to make sure that pretty much everything I had was enchanted. Mossy Shields are nice too, they grant a pile of extra HP.

Comment: Interestingly, a [blog post](http://www.gaslampgames.com/blog/2011/07/28/patch-status/) today indicates that in the coming patch heavy armour will have been tweaked to reduce piercing damage as well, so that will come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Wait for the patch where armor will help
- focus on block if you are heavy armor.
- I believe you can find items that have some resist for it
- Assassination

  ### - blackjack the monster sometimes so it sleeps instead of attacking
- Vampirism

  - Take some life back with each hit
  - Sparkle to stun
- Astrology has a passive chance on hit to AoE everything around you, sometimes stunning
- staff skills can stun sometimes

Comment: It happened only once to find an item with 2X resistance to slashing while I never found one with resistance to piercing in almost 40 hours. Anyway your suggestions are nice, I find vampirism and assassination very useful and they help to reach floor 6 for the first time. I am looking forward to the patch release.